# OpenCv Training Taking a long time

Tags: opencv, model, face-recognition

Hi I would like to ask if anybody has tried OpenCV.Eigenface.Train function on labelled faces of the wild if it had taken a long time for them as well?

Currently, training has lasted almost 24hr

Comment: This is an unclear question. Please visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to set how many faces you want to take from the dataset for the training purpose because there are probably a lot of images in the files you described.